# How to prevent from translating comments with gettext()

Tags: html, smarty, gettext

I am using gettext() to process internationalization of my website. The fact is that I use Smarty as template engine and I had to comment part of my html code by smarty's tag : {* *}. The problem is that these comments are ful l of code that I developed once but that I don't want to get rid of. So gettext() reads the inside (inbetween curly braces) code, and generates a .po file with lot of non necessary translation items. How can I prevent myself to have a clean po file with no extra translation items. A regexp on my code or a parameter to set with gettext() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [xgettext](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/gettext/manual/html_node/xgettext-Invocation.html) manual, these are the languages supported:
C, C++, ObjectiveC, PO, Shell, Python, Lisp, EmacsLisp, librep, Scheme, Smalltalk, Java, JavaProperties, C#, awk, YCP, Tcl, Perl, PHP, GCC-source, NXStringTable, RST, Glade

So unless one of these languages has smarty-like comments, {* *}, then I don't think you can (easily) bypass the commented code.

However, I'm **guessing** that a possible workaround would be to somehow compile all your templates and then run poedit across *.php files, not *.tpl. Since smarty comments wouldn't be included in the compiled templates, they would be excluded

Comment: Thanks for your answer : What do you mean exactly by compiling the files ?

Comment: When smarty runs, it produces intermediate php files which are then ran to create the actual HTML. You can find them under your $smarty->compile_dir (take a look at smarty_config.php)